# Most efficient way to verify equality of two large DataFrames that contain floats and NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`, that normally would be equal. I need to verify this equality in code. Unfortunately, I can't just use `df1.equals(df2)` because both DataFrames contain:

1. NaNs
2. Floats

Is there an efficient way to compare the entire DataFrame at once, instead of breaking them down to rows / columns and checking that the NaNs correspond and that the floats match as well within epsilon using `np.isclose()`?

Also, if I have to break down the `DataFrame`, is it more efficient to break it down to rows or columns (I suspect the latter)?

Comment: It's more efficient to break them down in columns because that's roughly the way they're stored in memory: A bunch of `Series` (for each column) all sharing the same index.

Comment: Also, from the docs: `NaNs in the same location are considered equal.` Why can't you use `df1.equals(df2)`?

Comment: @MohammadJafarMashhadi if I understand the docs correctly NaN's will be handled correctly, but slightly different floating point values won't be.

Comment: Can you use `assert_frame_equal()`?  It has a setting for precision, so you can compare, say, 5 digits after the decimal point: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Comment: Yup, `assert_frame_equal` is the way to go

Comment: @Mohammad where in the docs did you find that? See _"NaN values are considered different (i.e. NaN != NaN)"_ [df.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

Comment: [df.compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) says _"Matching NaNs will not appear as a difference."_ but it doesn't seem to have a tolerance for floats

Comment: `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal()` appears to be exactly what I need. In my testing over several small dataframes, `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal()` was moderately faster than row-wise comparison, which was slightly faster than column-wise comparison. Interestingly, results were reversed for large dataframes: for them, column-wise was fastest, followed by `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal()`, with row-wise being the slowest.

Comment: @RichieV https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html That's the way `df.eq` and `df.equals` are different